# print last two words of last line

Tags: awk, sed, cut

I have a script which returns few lines of output and I am trying to print the last two words of the last line (irrespective of number of lines in the output)

```
$ ./test.sh

service is running..
check are getting done
status is now open..
the test is passed
```

I tried running as below but it prints last word of each line.

```
$ ./test.sh |  awk '{ print $NF }'

running..
done
open..
passed
```

how do I print the last two words "is passed" using `awk` or `sed`?

Comment: `./test.sh | tail -1 | grep -o '\w\+\s\+\w\+$'`, unless you *have to* use sed and Awk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just say:

```
awk 'END {print $(NF-1), $NF}'
```

"normal" `awk`s store the last line ([but not all of them!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29970549/1983854)), so that it is still accessible by the time you reach the `END` block.

Then, it is a matter of printing the penultimate and the last one. This can be done using the `NF-1` and `NF` trick.

Comment: Yep, from the [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-And-BEGIN_002fEND.html#I_002fO-And-BEGIN_002fEND), even though _The POSIX standard specifies that NF is available in an END rule._ then we read that _the standard does not say that $0 is also preserved_.

Comment: True, maybe something like `awk 'END{if (NF>=2) print $(NF-1), $NF; else print $NF}'` is more general and prevents this edge case.

Answer (score 1):

For robustness if your last line can only contain 1 field and your awk doesn't retain the field values in the END section:

```
awk '{split($0,a)} END{print (NF>1?a[NF-1]OFS:"") a[NF]}'
```

Comment: I especially like the trick of not saying `print a,b` but saying `print a b` to prevent `OFS` to be printed if NF==1. +1 again (I did before!)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$s/.*\(\<..*\<.*\)/\1/p;d' file
```

This deletes all lines in the file but on the last line it replaces all words by the last two words and prints them if successful.