# How to divide outputs of two different commands?

Tags: ubuntu, awk, gawk

I want to divide two values with the ubuntu terminal, but the first number is the result of doing:

```
wc -l file.txt
```

i.e: 200

And the second number is obtained by typing:

```
gawk '{print $3}' file.txt | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

i.e: 20

How can I divide these two numbers (without using the numeric values, and using a code instead?)

Answer (score 2):

This is counting the lines of a file:

```
wc -l file.txt
```

This is counting the number of different items that occur in the 3rd column:

```
gawk '{print $3}' file.txt | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

All of it is something `awk` can do in an easy way:

```
awk '{uniq[$3]} END{print NR, length(uniq), NR/length(uniq)}' file.txt
```

That is:

- `{uniq[$3]}`
  to keep track of the items that appeared in the 3rd column
- `END{print NR, length(uniq), NR/length(uniq)}`
  to print the number of lines (`NR`) as well as the number of different items and its division. This is because `NR` in the `END` block [normally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29970549/1983854) holds the number of the last line that was read, and hence the number of lines, and [`length()`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html) is a function that returns the number of items in an array.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
1
2
3
1
2
3
$ awk '{uniq[$1]} END{print NR, length(uniq), NR/length(uniq)}' a
6 3 2
$ awk '{uniq[$1]} END{printf "lines: %d; different items: %d; proportion: %f\n", NR, length(uniq), NR/length(uniq)}' a
lines: 6; different items: 3; proportion: 2.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```
echo $(($(wc -l file.txt)  / $(gawk '{print $3}' file.txt | sort | uniq | wc -l)))
```

or

```
echo $(wc -l file.txt)/$(gawk '{print $3}' file.txt | sort | uniq | wc -l) | bc
```

or

```
expr $(wc -l file.txt) / $(gawk '{print $3}' file.txt | sort | uniq | wc -l)
```