# awk to store and reset variable from file

Tags: awk

Trying to use `awk` to lookup the string in `file1` (which is always just 1 field) in the same line of `file2`.  That is if row 1 is being used in `file1` then only row 1 is used in `file2`. Since it is possible for the value to be missing this is a check done to ensure it is there. This is just an idea so there probably is a better way, but I just wanted to see.  Thank you :).

**file1**

```
R_2017_01_13_12_11_56_user_S5-00580-24-Medexome
R_2017_01_13_14_46_04_user_S5-00580-25-Medexome
```

**file2**

```
The oldest folder is R_2017_01_13_12_11_56_user_S5-00580-24-Medexome, created on 2017-01-17+11:31:02.5035483130 and analysis done using v1.4 by cmccabe at 01/17/17 12:41:03 PM
```

desired output for `$filename`

```
R_2017_01_13_12_11_56_user_S5-00580-24-Medexome
```

After a bunch of processes are run using `$filename`, I need to reset that variable with a new one.

**file1** (after rerunning some process)

```
R_2017_01_13_12_11_56_user_S5-00580-24-Medexome
R_2017_01_13_14_46_04_user_S5-00580-25-Medexome
```

**file2** (after rerunning some process)

```
The oldest folder is R_2017_01_13_12_11_56_user_S5-00580-24-Medexome, created on 2017-01-17+11:31:02.5035483130 and analysis done using v1.4 by cmccabe at 01/17/17 12:41:03 PM
The oldest folder is R_2017_01_13_14_46_04_user_S5-00580-25-Medexome, created on 2017-01-17+06:53:07.3194950000 and analysis done using v1.4 by cmccabe at 01/18/17 06:59:08 AM
```

desired output for `$filename` now is (since this is value is new)

```
R_2017_01_13_14_46_04_user_S5-00580-25-Medexome
```

**awk**

```
filename=$(awk 'NR==1{print $1}' file1 file2)
```

Comment: so you want to print the last item from file1 that occurs in the same line as in file2?

Comment: Other way around I think, since `file1` can have multiple values in it, but `file2` will only have one until it is updated by the new process.  Thank you :).

Comment: so you always need to check _just_ the last line in file2?

Comment: Yes, that is correct :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check if the last line of file2 contains a string given in file1.

For this, you just have to read that last line and then see if it matches with any of the words in file1.

```
$ awk 'ENDFILE {line=$0} FNR<NR && line ~ $1' file2 file1
R_2017_01_13_14_46_04_user_S5-00580-25-Medexome
```

This uses:

- `ENDFILE {line=$0}`
  after reading a file, `$0` contains the last line that was read (well, [not always](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29970549/1983854), but I assume you have a modern version of `awk`, since [`ENDFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html) is a GNU awk extension). With this, we store this last line into `line`, so that we can use it when reading the next file.
- `FNR<NR && line ~ $1`
  while reading the file1, check if the given word is present in the stored line. If so, `print` is automatically triggered.
  This uses the `FNR<NR` trick, where `FNR` holds the number of the line in the current file, while `NR` the number of line in general. This way, `FNR==NR` is only true while reading the first file and `FNR<NR` from the second on.

Comment: NIce [this is a filler].

Comment: how can this value be stored in `$filename` variable or if a file is created that stores this line can that be used by the subsequent scripts?  Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris of course, just say `filename=$(awk 'ENDFILE {line=$0} FNR<NR && line ~ $1' file2 file1)` and `$filename` will hold the desired value.

Comment: Thank you both very much :).

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to check the last line of `file2` *continuously*, you could:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}{for(i in a)if(i ~ $0) print i}' file1 <(tail -f file2)
```

Explained:

- `NR==FNR{a[$1];next}` read into `a` array the search terms from `file1`
- `file2` is `tail -f`'d into awk using process substitution, ie. it reads a record from the end of `file2`, goes thru all search words in `a` and looks them from the record, printing search word if there is a match